# How to use printf to show the results of a calculation?

Tags: shell-script, printf

My program is

```
#!/bin/sh
printf 'Please enter salary amount: '
read salary
TAX="echo $salary * 0.15 | bc"
NET="echo $salary + $TAX | bc"

printf "Net Salary= %.2f" $NET
printf "\n"
```

But whatever I try I can't get the output I expect.
Right now I am getting

```
$ . 3_net_salary.sh 
Please enter salary amount: 300
-bash: printf: echo: invalid number
-bash: printf: +: invalid number
-bash: printf: echo: invalid number
-bash: printf: 1_simple.awk: invalid number
-bash: printf: 1_simple_awk.sh: invalid number
-bash: printf: 2_simple_awk.sh: invalid number
-bash: printf: 2_simple_before.awk: invalid number
-bash: printf: 3_net_salary.sh: invalid number
-bash: printf: 4_purchase_amounts.sh: invalid number
-bash: printf: alert_spec.rb: invalid number
-bash: printf: awk_passwd.sh: invalid number
-bash: printf: numbers.txt: invalid number
-bash: printf: sed_to_change_should_syntax_to_expect-to: invalid number
-bash: printf: should_to_expect: invalid number
-bash: printf: t1_spec.rb: invalid number
-bash: printf: test001.txt: invalid number
-bash: printf: test_1_spec.rb: invalid number
-bash: printf: test_2_spec.rb: invalid number
-bash: printf: |: invalid number
-bash: printf: bc: invalid number
-bash: printf: |: invalid number
-bash: printf: bc: invalid number
Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 300.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 300.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.15Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00Net Salary= 0.00
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense - bc is an interactive calculator. You don't need to `printf` back and forth like that - you can just call `bc`. You can print arbitrary strings to stdout just by enclosing them in double-quotes - and `bc` will read an infile with your `bc` script *then* to/from the terminal interactively if you wish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not doing what you think you're doing. This command:

```
TAX="echo $salary * 0.15 | bc"
```

Does not run anything, there is no calculation. That assigns a string to the variable `$TAX`. Then, because you're not quoting the variable when you pass it to `printf`, the `*` will expand to everything in the current directory. To illustrate:

```
$ ls
file1  file2
foo="echo 12 * 4 | bc"
$ echo $foo
echo 12 file1 file2 4 | bc
```

As you can see above, the `*` expanded to the contents of the directory and no calculation was made. In order to assign the result of a command to a variable, you should use `var=$(command)`, not quotes.

So, a working version of your script would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf 'Please enter salary amount: '
read salary
TAX=$(printf '%s * %s\n' "$salary" "0.15" | bc)
NET=$(printf '%s + %s\n' "$salary" "$TAX" | bc)

printf "Net Salary= %.2f\n" $NET
```

When debugging something you should always think of printing your variables to understand what they contain.

Comment: There is  no need for the unreadable `printf '%s * %s\n' "$salary" "0.15"` . One can use `echo "0.15 * $salary"`. the "-quotes suppress the filename globbing but allows the evaluation of variables.

Comment: @miracle173 readibility is in the eye of the beholder I guess. However, there are [very real reasons](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22222) to prefer `printf` even if you might find it less readable.